# Get iconv to convert my string

Tags: php, unicode, iconv

I have the following string:

`ᴰᴶ Bagi`

Is it possible to let iconv make it into `DJ Bagi`?

First I tried with:

```
$text = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

Which resulted in the following notice:

```
Notice: iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string
```

On the PHP site I saw someone using:

`//IGNORE//TRANSLIT`

While this prevents the notice I only get:

`Bagi`

Comment: Have you tried with //IGNORE//TRANSLIT (in that order)? Several people on the PHP site have reported strange behavior when using the order you describe.

Comment: "Illegal character in input string" might mean that it isn't UTF-8.

Comment: @TobiasE: I'm sorry that's what I've tried. Note to self: don't try to type just copy paste.

Comment: @Pekka: Ok. So what is it? Should I be using UTF-16?

Comment: @PeeHaa it depends on what encoding the characters actually are in. Where are you getting the data from, a database or directly from the text file? As a blind bet, there is a `ᴰ` character in the ISO-8859-1 character set as well, so you might try using that as the input encoding.

Comment: @Pekka: I'm retrieving the text from http://soundcloud.com/bagi (using an API call). BTW using UTF-16 fails :P

Comment: The data there is definitely UTF-8. What are you using to fetch it?

Comment: @Pekka: I'm using cURL to fetch it and the result is in json format.

Comment: Can you show the code? Are you doing anything with the data that might turn it into ISO-8859-1? Did you try ISO-8859-1 as the start encoding? Also I think "ASCII" (without the US) is also valid

Comment: When I try ISO-8859-1 as start encoding I get: `a0ap Bagi`

Comment: @PeeHaa in that case the data is okay, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially thought that this is an encoding problem on your end, but if I copy + paste those characters locally from the soundcloud source page:

```
ᴰᴶ Bagi
```

and try to iconv them, I get the same result as you do. That means that the data is UTF-8, but **iconv does not recognize `ᴰ` as a "child" of `D`**. Unable to convert the character, it complains (a bit misleadingly IMO) about an illegal character.

**Edit:** This seems indeed true. Superscript D is not in the [Unicode Superscripts and Subscripts range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts), but it's a [phonetic character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_symbols_in_Unicode). That's probably why they can't be mapped back to their "parent" letter. [Here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d30/index.htm) is more info on `ᴰ`

As far as I can see, your only choice is to replace the characters manually.

The most primitive example of a replace is

```
str_replace("ᴰ", "D", $string);
```

(note that your source file needs to be  stored as UTF-8 for this to work)

For an elegant solution, you could build an array out of the source and replacement characters, and pass that to the `str_replace` call.

Or call DJ Bagi and tell him to get the damn letters straight. You will notice that Soundcloud's URL builder encountered exactly the same problem.

```
soundcloud.com/bagi
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Pekka! Both for your hard work and for this explanation. I think I will go the same way as the Soundcloud builder. Although I'm considering telling Dj Bagi to f#*cking change his name and direct him to this question :)

Comment: @PeeHaa you're welcome. It's indeed DJ Bagi who is to blame here! :)